# getByXpath() not working inside frame

Tags: java, xpath, frame, htmlunit

i am new to Htmlunit and trying to extract data from a website http://capitaline.com/new/index.asp. I have logged into the website successfully. When we log into website there are three frames.

1. One on the top to search for the company(like ACC ltd.) for which we are extracting data.
2. 2nd frame has a tree which provide links to various data we want to look at.
3. 3rd frame has the resulted data outcome on the basis of link you clicked in frame.

I managed to get the frame i need below:

```
HtmlPage companyAtGlanceTopWindow =(HtmlPage)companyAtGlanceLink.click().getEnclosingWindow().getTopWindow().getEnclosedPage();
HtmlPage companyAtGlanceFrame = (HtmlPage)companyAtGlanceTopWindow.getFrameByName("mid2").getEnclosedPage();
System.out.println(companyAtGlanceFrame.toString()); // This line returns the frame URL as i can see in my browser.
```

Output of print statement is

```
HtmlPage(http://capitaline.com/user/companyatglance.asp?id=CGO&cocode=6)@1194282974
```

Now i want my code to navigate down to the table inside this frame and for that i am using getByXPath() but it gives me nullPointerException. Here is the code for that.

```
HtmlTable companyGlanceTable1 = companyAtGlanceFrame.getFirstByXPath("/html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table");
```

My XPath for the current webpage(after i clicked the link)from which i am trying to extract table is seems correct, as it is copied from chrome element inspect. Please suggest some way to extract the table. I have done this type of extraction before but there i had id of table so, i used it.
Here is the HTML code for the table in the webpage.

```
<table width="100%" class = "tablelines" border = "0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to know that can you see the inner contents of each iframes in console (print asXml()), are they nested iframes?
well try this

```
   List<WebWindow> windows = webClient.getWebWindows();
   for(WebWindow w : windows){
     HtmlPage hpage = (HtmlPage) w.getEnclosedPage();
     System.out.println(hpage.asXml());
   }
```

once you can see the contents,

```
   HtmlPage hpage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getWebWindowByName(some_name).getEnclosedPage();
```

then using xpath grab your table contents(make sure your xpath is correct). It will work.(worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you RDD for your feedback. 
I solved the problem. Actually issue was not with the frame but with the XPath provided by chrome. 
XPath Provided by chrome is:

```
/html/body/**table[4]**/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table
```

But the XPath worked for me is:

```
 /html/body/**table[3]**/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table
```

It seems as, XPath provided by chrome has some glitch when there is a table within the path(Or may be some bug in htmlunit itself). I did many experiments and found that chrome always gives `../../table[row+1]/..` as XPath, while working XPath for htmlunit is `../../table[row]/..`

SO, this code is working fine for me

```
HtmlTable companyGlanceTable1 = companyAtGlanceFrame.getFirstByXPath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table");
```